# How to programmatically create output redirection in bash

Tags: bash, io-redirection

I'm writing a test script and it has a lot of repetition in it, and I'm looking for ways to reduce these code duplication.
So I thought it would be nice to programmatically create the redirect part of the commands.

Here is a minimal example: (In the real script I would generate different output file names in `x()`)

```
#!/bin/bash

set -x

x() {
  echo '> out.txt 2> err.txt'
}

./someProgram $(x)
```

My hope would be that `stdout` would end up in `out.txt` and `stderr` in `err.txt`.
But bash quotes the string. So the resulting command is `./someProgram '>' out.txt '2>' err.txt` instead of `./someProgram > out.txt 2> err.txt`.

Here is the output of the example:

```
++ x
++ echo '> out.txt   2> err.txt'
+ ./someProgram '>' out.txt '2>' err.txt
.....
```

So is there a possibility that `'>'` and `'2>'` won't get quoted?

Comment: Perhaps you just want `exec > out.txt 2> err.txt`

Comment: Have you considered to invert the flow? Instead of `someProgram $(x)` you can do it like this: `x someProgram`, i.e. the `x` function accepts an executable along with optional arguments and redirects its stdout and stderr as you wish

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It's hard to way without more context, but probably you just want to use `exec` judiciously.  I won't vouch for the portability of the following, but in bash 5.0.16  you can do:

```
x() { shift; "$@"; } > $1.out 2> $1.err
x filename ./someProgram
```

To run `./someProgram` with the output directed to `filename.out` and the error stream written to `filenmae.err`

Comment: Wrt *I won't vouch for the portability of the following* [standard](https://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/utilities/V3_chap02.html#tag_18_09_05) is a bit unclear on this, it says *The operands to the command temporarily shall become the positional parameters during the execution of the **compound-command**;* but I think they should support this usage, it's really cool.

Comment: `exec` was not the right approach but re-thinking the flow. I use a similar approach to yours with `shift`. Thanks for your insight/inspiration!